# What is the best way to not use allowmainthreadqueries() using Android Room?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I always use `allowmainthreadqueries()` in Android Room. But many people say it is not recommend to do it.
With this function, Room is very easy to use.
But if i should change my app to not using this function, How do I do that?
Is there an effective way to do it?

Comment: The main thread is responsible to handle user interface events. If you execute long running actions on it you risk to make the UI unresponsive.

Comment: What are the cases where you need to run db queries on main ui thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It is not a good approach to query DB on Main Thread. There are different ways, to keep the DB operation off the main(UI) thread, Mainly

1. Kotlin Coroutines. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-coroutines-and-room#0
2. RxJava(RxAndroid)  https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757
3. LiveData           https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#0
4. Executors
5. AsycTask

Out of the above, the best option would always depend upon what is your use case.
But the first three are the best options to use. since they provide a callback on the result of a query.

Comment: Maybe Livedata would be the best choise. Thanks.

Comment: As I have already mentioned, it depends upon your case, Flow(coroutine) and Flowable(RxJava) are the best options when you want to update the view when some data inserted to DB, you don't have to query every time data inserted, The Flow/Flowable will always give you latest update.